# chmod after reboot -> Permissions change

Tags: shell, ubuntu, permissions, chmod, reboot

I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 and I make chmod +x to a file, but, when I reboot the computer, the permissions change. How can I make to put chmod permanent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't make it permanent, but you can automate the chmod command at boot-time by putting it in /etc/rc.local.